# Agregar una imagen en un JPanel en una misma clase

Tags: java, imagen, clase

hola el siguiente es mi código, pero aunque no me muestra error y compila, simplemente no funciona, no se si cometí un error o si puse mal la imagen ya desde el principio, pues la imagen la tengo desde la carpeta de descargas.

```
 package source;

 import java.awt.Container;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.net.URL;


 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class imagen extends JFrame {

public Image imagenfondo;
public URL fondo;   

public imagen(){
    this.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
    this.setTitle("ventana");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    fondo = this.getClass().getResource("/source/puzle106.jpg");
    imagenfondo = new ImageIcon(fondo).getImage();

    Container contenedor = getContentPane();

    contenedor.add(panel);



}
public JPanel panel= new JPanel(){

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
g.drawImage(imagenfondo, 0,0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

}
};

public static void main(String [] args){

//  Principal ventana  = new Principl();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores, para empezar si estas ejecutando el codigo de la misma manera en que lo tienes, obviamente va a compilar pero no mostrara nada por que en el main no le has dicho que muestre nada, por lo que deberias por lo menos instanciar a tu clase Imagen en el main para que todos los parametros que colocaste en el constructor se realicen.

> Recuerda que es de buenas practicas escribir las clases con la primer letra en mayúscula, por lo que te recomendaría arreglarlo.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

    Imagen imagen = new Imagen();
}
```

Los otros detalles que hay que arreglar son con respecto a imagenFondo, deberias ponerla mejor como una BufferedImage ya que Image como tal es una clase abstracta, si la dejas como esta te saldra un error. Para poder conseguir la imagen con BufferedImage lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
imagenfondo = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(ruta));
```

y ya no necesitarias a URL.
Por ultimo antes de agregar el panel al container, asegurate que lo hayas establecido como visible.